# Su fails despite entering in the correct password

Tags: ubuntu, login, sudo, ubuntu-11.04

I just recently installed Ubuntu 11.04 on my desktop, and I only entered in one password during the install process. This password works to log into the machine, run updates etc. When I open up the terminal, and try to use su and I enter in the same password... I get an Authentication failure.

I've booted my computer up in recovery mode, and reset the password from the command line, but I'm still getting the same authentication error.

If anyone could help me out, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I'm sorry but have you even bothered to google or read documentation?

Comment: I figured with as obvious as the answer was there would have to be one guy that would say something like that. *sigh* Now that I know the answer, I'm able to better phrase the question so that google pulls up more relevant results... but that didn't help me when I was looking through page after page of tutorials on how to reset the root password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ubuntu the root account is locked by default. To perform administrative tasks in Ubuntu you need to use `sudo` instead. If you need a root shell, use `sudo -i`.

Of course you can just unlock the root account with `sudo passwd root` but after that you are not doing thing 'in Ubuntu way'. Is that a good thing or not, you decide.